# playframework - how to automatically increment evolutions

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

So I'm using playframework 2.0 and my application is ready for release. as I have been developing I have noticed that:
conf\evolutions\default\1.sql has been automatically changing each time I add/modify my model layer.
As I am about to release my application I was wondering how do I set this to start adding it to 2.sql instead of 1? I would like to tag/branch the revision so that if I need to upgrade my release in the future the system will notice that it has 1.sql installed so it will only need to run 2.sql.

I am currently using a JDBC databse, and noticed that during development if I made any changes it would update 1.sql and then the next time I ran the application it would wipe all my data clean.

So how do I make it so evolution 1 is finished?

I currently have the config option: applyEvolutions.default=true

is this a bad idea for release?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

### It's definitely bad idea

Ebean doesn't create ALTERS but CREATE version of DDLs, so in case you'll modify any model and will send it to the production it will **DROP** all tables and recreate them. Of course all data will be lost.

Therefore you need to remove two first lines from the `1.sql` to disable modyfying the file by Ebean.

From now you'll need create files like `2.sql` and next manually. In these new files you need to add only modifying statement.

Comment: So ebean wont automatically create the modify statment in my 2.sql?